# Forzar a encontrar una lista de valores en mysql

Tags: mysql

Buen día!

Tengo una tabla con varios campos, de los cuales solo me importan 5 (**Patente, Pedimento, SeccionAduanera, Fraccion y ClaveDocumento** y una suma, tengo que entregar máximo 50 resultados.

Lo que necesito es que este en el resultado el 100% o lo mas cercano de las Patentes, SeccionAduanera y ClaveDocumento.
Por ejemplo, tengo estas **Patentes:** 3475, 1200, 3452, 3072, 3076, 3770. **SeccionAduanera:** 170, 240, 430, 470, 750, 800. **ClaveDocumento:** A1, AF, F4, F5, IN, V1.

Hago la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Patente, Pedimento, SeccionAduanera, ClaveDocumento, SUM(ValorAduana) as Total 
FROM `Tabla` 
WHERE auditoria_id = '4' 
AND TipoOperacion = '1' 
GROUP BY Patente, Pedimento, SeccionAduanera, ClaveDocumento 
ORDER BY Total DESC
LIMIT 50
```

El problema es que me esta haciendo falta una ClaveDocumento (F4), una SeccionAduanera (800) y una patente (3770) dentro de los 50 resultados.

Necesito saber si hay alguna manera de decirle a mysql que me entregue forzosamente todos los valores de esos 3 campos, o haciendo joins, pero ya se me cerro la mente.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En tu SELECT solo estas discriminando por medio del WHERE, que los registros posean las siguientes condiciones (auditoria_id = '4' y TipoOperacion = '1'), por lo que debes asegurar que los registros que poseen ClaveDocumento (F4), SeccionAduanera (800) y patente (3770), cumplan con esas condiciones iniciales.

Así mismo, debes considerar que de acuerdo a la forma como estas ordenando esos registros pueden ubicarse después de esos primeros 50.

Si los registros que mencionas estan faltando, cumplen con las condiciones indicadas en el WHERE, es seguro que se encuentre fuera del rango de los primeros 50. Esta conclusión se debe a que no estas haciendo discriminaciones por esos campos (ClaveDocumento, SeccionAduanera, patente).

Puedes ajustar el ORDER BY de forma que los registros que necesitas se muestren, combinando de la forma mas conveniente. Solo como ejemplo:

```
ORDER BY Patente ASC, SeccionAduanera DESC, ClaveDocumento ASC, Total DESC
```

Por ultimo, una forma de forzar estos valores es que incluyas en el WHERE las condiciones que precisas.

```
...
WHERE auditoria_id = '4' 
AND TipoOperacion = '1' AND  
ClaveDocumento = 'F4'AND SeccionAduanera = 800 y patente = 3770 
...
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Si entiendo lo que me dices y precisamente estan despues de los 50 resultados, ya intente con AND ClaveDocumento IN ('....') AND Patente In ('...') ETC pero es exactamente lo mismo que no ponerlos, ya que el IN los trata como OR. Lo que necesito es decirle a mysql dame por lo menos un valor que contenta Patente = 3475 uno con Patente =1200 y asi con los otros campos y valores, los ordeno por ValorAduana porque le dan preferencia a los que tienen mas valor. Por lo tanto si me hacen falta solo 2 registros para obtener el 100% de esos campos, los puedo meter al final.

Answer (score 0):

En funcion de lo que me comentas, creo que puedes hacer algo como esto para obtener el resultado que buscas:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT t1.* FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT Patente, Pedimento, SeccionAduanera, ClaveDocumento, SUM(ValorAduana) as Total 
FROM `Tabla` 
WHERE auditoria_id = '4' AND TipoOperacion = '1' 
GROUP BY Patente, Pedimento, SeccionAduanera, ClaveDocumento 
ORDER BY Total DESC
LIMIT 47) AS t1
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.* FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT Patente, Pedimento, SeccionAduanera, ClaveDocumento, SUM(ValorAduana) as Total 
FROM `Tabla` 
WHERE auditoria_id = '4' AND ClaveDocumento = 'F4' AND TipoOperacion = '1'
LIMIT 1) AS t2
UNION ALL
SELECT t3.* FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT Patente, Pedimento, SeccionAduanera, ClaveDocumento, SUM(ValorAduana) as Total 
FROM `Tabla` 
WHERE auditoria_id = '4' AND SeccionAduanera = 800 AND TipoOperacion = '1' 
LIMIT 1) AS t3
UNION ALL
SELECT t4.* FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT Patente, Pedimento, SeccionAduanera, ClaveDocumento, SUM(ValorAduana) as Total 
FROM `Tabla` 
WHERE auditoria_id = '4' AND patente = 3770 AND TipoOperacion = '1'
LIMIT 1) AS t4
) Tx ORDER BY 5 DESC
```

Ajusta de acuerdo a tus necesidades, al final la consulta devolverá 50 registros.Observa que en los segundos querys no estan presentes las clausulas GROUP BY ni ORDER BY por que se esta solicitando solo un registro, pero esto también lo puedes ajustas a tu criterio.

El incluirlos dentro de Tx, persigue poder ordenarlos por Total los 50 registros.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Tuve que modificar un poco la consulta por los GROUP BY que me daban error, se me repite un resultado casi al final, pero me diste la idea de como reunir varias consultas.